# I am trying to put the contents of a checkedlistbox into an array but keep getting an error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

```
Dim a As Integer
    While a < CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1

        a = a + 1
    End While
```

It crashes at:
WordBankArray(a) = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(a)

Comment: `WordBankArray` must be Nothing (not instanced) see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: You would need to show where/how WorldBankArray is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=0;

foreach (ListItem li in CheckedListBox1.Items)
{
    a=a+1
    if (li.Selected)
    {
        WorkBankArray(a) = CheckedListBox1.Items[a].ToString();
    }
}
```

you can adjust the code as per your situation this is the broader guideline.